# Intellisense delay in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

When editing C++ code on a fast machine, Intellisense pops up **way** too quick. Most of the time Intellisense is not needed (and unwanted). There are occasions when the popup is useful, of course, so I don't want to disable Intellisense altogether.

I'm either having to hit ESC or move the mouse to get the popup to go away. If you're working quickly, this interrupts the flow and after a while gets annoying.

Is there a delay for Intellisense? Something along the lines of "Only pop up if user does nothing for 1000ms". If I actually need Intellisense, I don't mind hitting a key and waiting a bit or hivering the mouse over a variable.

Have checked Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced > Intellisense but did not see anything that configures this.

Comment: I believe there isn't any feature like delay in Visual Studio 2019, it was proposed some years back on uservoice. I don't know what have they done with that suggestion as it appears now to be removed. Well here is a workaround for your problem, just disable auto quick info feature. You can manually trigger it by `Ctrl + I`. [Here is more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @brc-dd: Thanks, that's helpful. Just playing the setting now and it is an improvement.