# Set Intellisense delay (VS 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Writing C# code in `Visual Studio 2019`. The *constant* popups as you type or position the mouse are very distracting. In `Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages (or your language)`, you can disable all popups as you type by untciking `Auto list members`, but this is not what I need. Firstly I don't want to disable them completely and secondly this doesn't affect popups when you hover over a variable.

Ideally, I'd like popups more sparingly and only after a long-ish delay (say 1000ms). Currently they appear nearly instantly whenever I type any character or move the mouse over the code.

Can the delay be configured?

### Update

According to a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892255), Visual Studio does not currently support a delay. But the experience for C# coding can be improved at `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Intellisense`. Find the option `Show completion list after a character is typed` and untick it.

Comment: "Unable to execute your request" three times. Wasted an hour trying to add this to your "Suggest a feature" site. If you send me an email to abdekker dot online <AT> gmail d.o.t. com I can send you the text for a feature request.

Comment: I already suggested the feature for you. Since the process would take a long time, so you have to use my workaround manually so far.  Please check my updated answer and hope it could give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

**Actually**, VS does not such feature to make a delay for code Intellisense.

**Suggestion**

**So** my suggestion is that you can disable the option `Show completion list after a character is typed` just as you said.

**And** then if you want to invoke Intellisense, you should type `Ctrl + Space` manually to invoke the Intellisense.

**In this way**, you can invoke the Intellisense anytime based on your needs.

**Besides**, if you still want this requirement, I suggest you could [suggest your feature on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

[image]

**Also**, you can share the link here and anyone including us will vote it so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention.

**Update 1**

I already suggested the feature for you and you can [check the link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1277620/a-teature-that-could-make-the-intellisense-with-a.html).

You can vote on it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail. Hope the Team will consider the idea carefully and give us a satisfactory reply.

**Since** the process would take a long time, so you have to use my workaround manually so far.

Comment: Thanks. Have added my vote and supplied a more detailed comment.

Comment: @AlainD. Since these are all the things we can do now, I suggest you could mark the answer. If you still want this feature, you have to wait or try the workaround which I list above. And hope the Team could give you a satisfactory reply.